# Can I host a nodejs GRPC server on google cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, grpc

I have a nodejs GRPC server running on a AWS instance and would like to move to a google cloud function.  Is this possible?  What are my serverless options

Comment: No, it does not seem that way: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/choose-endpoints-option#grpc_apis_arent_supported_on_or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Yes, it is possible** to use [**Cloud Functions**](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) for your **gRPC service**, as it offers a **serverless event-driven platform** that reacts to certain **events or HTTP requests**. Plus, your language of choice, **Node.js**, is supported.

Depending on your **specific use case**, you may also explore **other Google serverless options**:

> > 1. [**Cloud Run** (*Beta*)](https://cloud.google.com/run/) - Serverless compute platform that enables you to run stateless container via HTTP requests.
> > 2. [**Cloud Run on GKE** (*Beta*)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup) - Google Kubernetes Engine add-on for Cloud Run.
> > 3. [**App Engine standard environment**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/) - Fully-managed serverless application platform for web and API backends. To organize your many functions, you can implement Cloud Endpoints for API Management, more especifically **[Cloud Endpoints for gRPC](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/about-grpc)**

Here's the **[GCP serverless options](https://cloud.google.com/serverless-options/) diagram**, so you can take a look at the bigger picture and **decide what works best** for you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to invoke Cloud Functions via gRPC in production. There is a way to do so during testing but only for a very limited number of times per 100 seconds. App Engine doesn't support it either while Cloud Run supports ONLY unary gRPC calls (not streaming gRPC).

Comment: "(..) while Cloud Run supports ONLY unary gRPC calls (not streaming gRPC)" , this no longer is true. It supports any type of gRPC request now.

Comment: For cloud function there are several options, but no gRPC option.