# Google Cloud Functions in Golang and gRPC

Tags: google-cloud-functions, grpc-go

I am looking into migrating one of my apps from gRPC service into a set Google Cloud Functions. That feels really tempting, and from what I found - gRPC works over HTTP/2 that is supported by Cloud functions directly.

From [what I learned](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md) the name of the function is actually the part of the URL ( path ). But yet I can find only REST-gRPC [reverse proxies](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) and various workarounds.

I found [this post](https://blog.coinbase.com/grpc-to-aws-lambda-is-it-possible-4b29a9171d7f) related to AWS Lambda / API Gateway, and from there it looks like with GCF there shouldn't be that limitation as with the AWS.

Is there an example of gRPC deployed in Google Cloud Functions?

Comment: I could not find any examples of gRPC deploying on Google Cloud Functions. I can confirm that it is actually possible to use Cloud Functions for your gRPC service, but there are other  GCP serverless options depending on your use case. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57835237/can-i-host-a-nodejs-grpc-server-on-google-cloud-functions) I attached a stackoverflow post that goes more into the different options you have available. [Here](https://medium.com/@petomalina/%EF%B8%8Fserverless-grpc-with-cloud-run-bab3622a47da) you will find a tutorial on Cloud Run with gRPC. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I found some information about Cloud Run, at the moment it looks a bit like an overkill for some pretty simple function interface to the Datastore - like there must be a gRPC server, and a Docker container just to serve a single function call.